# How to find table size and memory consumption of STL hash_map?

Tags: c++, hash

I want to know how stl hash_map is implemented. How do I find out what the table size is and the memory space the map consumes? This is in C++.

Comment: Okay, I'll twist that arm: for crissake, what implementation of the STL are you using?

Comment: Your title asked for the collision rate, but the body asks 2 totally different things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "stl hash_map". There is an unordered_map in TR1, but I assume you're not using that or you would have said unordered_map.

As someone pointed out, unordered_map has "bucket_count" to determine the number of buckets. You can iterate over each bucket, get it's size ("bucket_size(size_t bucket_num)"), multiply that by the size of a pair of key and values, and add them all up to give you a *rough estimate* of the memory used. There may be non-portable ways which are implementation defined. It will obviously be implemention defined for whatever hash_map class you're using.

Comment: @SuperString As I said in the above answer: stdext::hash_map is old and busted. It's a Microsoft extension that is no longer maintained. Don't use it. Use std::tr1::unordered_map instead.

Answer (score 1):

This blog entry on [C++ STL Hash Containers and Performance](http://codemonkeyan.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-stl-hash-containers-and-performance.html) is a good looking explanation of STL hash map.  See if it helps you.

Comment: Doesn't tell me what the table size is :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bucket_count`.

Comment: I dont know why I am getting this:

hash.cpp(247) : error C2039: 'bucket_count' : is not a member of 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>'
        with
        [
            _Kty=std::string,
            _Ty=int
        ]

Comment: stdext::hash_map is old and busted. Don't use it.